# Edited text to database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, tinymce

I have a question about sending big documents to the database. When i insert my edited word doc with colors on some words into tinyMCE the text display properly. But sending to the database fails because of commas in the text i guess. Is there a simple way to fix this?

Comment: I'd be willing to bet it's because you don't escape your inputs properly, or use prepared statements. But with no code, who knows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $yourtext = $conn->real_escape_string($yourtext); //$conn is the mysql connection
```

if this succeed then it was a escaping problem

Comment: that was simple and stupid of me i didn't try that! Thank you very much!! :)

Comment: @Marvinoo_ you are welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use real_escape_string function,and also you can use a trick so that firstly save all contents of tinyMCE into a temporary file then you can read or insert the file into your database.